# Web site has an extra white space on small screens (less then the page width)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, viewport

I am building this website for one of my new iOS apps.

It works fine on most Desktops but on the iPad an iPhone I have extra white space on the right of the screen, I checked and it happens on every screen that is less then 1000 pixels.

It seems like the 100% with divs are not filling the screen.

What could be the problem ?

**EDIT**
Sorry:).
Here si the link -
[EnglishClubApp](http://www.englishclubapp.com)

Thanks, Shani

Comment: share your code if you want to someone can help you

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: @Alireza41  Yes, I believe a link will help :)